# Moped vs Mongo-ruby-driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb, moped

I'm going to write a ruby application and I need access to mongodb database.

What are the diferences between Moped and Mongo-ruby-driver?
What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Moped is abandoned, so there's really no choice here :)

Comment: Last commit was 24 days ago. Why do you say that is abandoned?

Comment: Last time I heard, Durran is employed by Mongodb Inc and is busy rewriting the ruby driver. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/commits/master